# Embedding C++ Objects into QML with Context Properties

Tags: ubuntu-touch, c++, qml, qt5

According to Qt5 documentation: [exposing methods including qt slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-methods-including-qt-slots) all public slots of C++ classes that inherit from QObject, are accessible from QML
Here what I did:

**C++**

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doStuffFromQmlSlot()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }

public:
    MyClass()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }
};
```

my **main.cpp** contains:

```
MyClass myClass;
QQmlEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "myclass", &myClass );
QQmlComponent component( &engine, QUrl::fromLocalFile("qml/qtquick-01/main.qml") );
component.create();
```

**QML**

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            myclass.doStuffFromQmlSlot();

            Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Actually the QtCreator seems to recognixe the exposed **myclass** object into the QML as it enables auto-completion of both class name (myclass) and the public slot doStuffFromQmlSlot().
When I run the application I unfortunately got the following error:

**ReferenceError: myclass is not defined**

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I posted on AskUbuntu as I found several questions regarding ubuntu-phone here. I agree that the topic is really programming specific, so the question is a good candidate for StackOverflow

Comment: QML is a core progamming language for ubuntu & ubuntu-touch and hence is on-topic here, please re-open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reused your qml file to start a fresh project in QtCreator.

Please find below the files I used to compile and use the application successfully:

the project file: **test.pro**

```
# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

HEADERS += myclass.h
```

**myclass.h:**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <qdebug.h>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doStuffFromQmlSlot()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }

public:
    MyClass()
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
    }
};
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "myclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    MyClass myClass;

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myclass", &myClass);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and **qml/main.qml** being exactly the snippet provided in your question

if you start the project using QtCreator you'll also have the qtquick2applicationviewer/ folder ready to be used.
Then `qmake && make && ./test` will launch the application.
If you click on the text element you'll get:

```
MyClass::MyClass() 
void MyClass::doStuffFromQmlSlot()
```

Comment: That worked! here what I was doing wrong: I was adding the classes to the wrong Context. Did not realized that the _QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer_ is a QmlEngine as well.