# Ubuntu SDK open file dialog

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml, dialog

I've started playing with the SDK to start developing an application.

The application will be something that will allow me to filter records in an CSV file by a search term. But does a file dialog exist so that the file can be located and how do I use it?

Comment: Please, could you put some of your time to read askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @SylvainPineau I know about accepting answers, but want to spent time testing your answer which means reading up on the links - which I will do this weekend. I also left some time for more answers, but thanks for the link/comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options that will depend on the Ubuntu version you're using (or plan to use).

- **Before 14.04 (Qt version are 5.0.x)**

  The only way to open a file dialog window is to use some C++ code.
  You'll have to expose a method that is a public slot to access it from your QML application.

  Visit the following links to get a template to start with:

  - [Exposing Attributes of C++ Types to QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-methods-including-qt-slots)
  - [Embedding C++ Objects into QML with Context Properties](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431368/qml-getting-referenceerror-when-accessing-public-c-slot-from-qml/431458#431458)

  Then your public slot can call the following `QFileDialog` function: [getOpenFileName()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName)

  ```
  QString GuiEngine::GetCSVFileName(void)
  {
      QString prompt = "Open File";

      return QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(NULL, \
                                          prompt, \
                                          "report.csv", \
                                          tr("CSV files (*.csv)"), \
                                          NULL, \
                                          QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
  }
  ```

  **Note**: it will only work with the [QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) option
  as native rendering creates a ghost window in addition to the File dialog (See [bug #1214914](https://bugs.launchpad.net/checkbox-ihv-ng/+bug/1214914))

It will create a window like the one below:

[image]

- **14.04 (Qt version 5.2.1)**

  In that case, implementing a [FileDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html) is much more easy to do as there's no need to write C++ code.

  Here is a minimal example to open a file dialog and exit after the user chooses a file:

  ```
  import QtQuick 2.1
  import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0

  FileDialog {
      id: fileDialog
      title: "Please choose a file"
      onAccepted: {
          console.log("You chose: " + fileDialog.fileUrls)
          Qt.quit()
      }
      onRejected: {
          console.log("Canceled")
          Qt.quit()
      }
      Component.onCompleted: visible = true
  }
  ```

Comment: Will both of these work on the phone as well since they don't make use of the Ubuntu components?

Comment: They should even though the Qt5.2 solution will try to find the best way to render the Dialog window

Comment: What's the outcome of your tests?

Comment: Unprogressfull, I don't know which C++ file to add the procedure to nor to which one to add the exposing of the procedure to - no c++ files exist. I therefore tried to create one (source and class) but get an error that it failed to add it to the `<project>.qmlproject` file.

Comment: Try yo reuse the app skeleton I've attached to this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/431368/qml-getting-referenceerror-when-accessing-public-c-slot-from-qml/431458#431458) if you want to develop with C++. You could also take the easy way by developing with 14.04 in a VM then switch to a full install when released (April 17th)