# What are the steps needed to implement a Qt class or member function into a QML project for Ubuntu-Touch?

Tags: application-development, programming, qt, ubuntu-sdk, qml

Qt contains many classes and functions that are useful for a QML project, but not readily available. The existing solutions do not employ a method that is platform independent, thus it is unclear whether it will work for ubuntu-touch devices.

In order to add the functionality of a Qt class or one of its member functions, what steps need to be followed, and why do they need to be included?

Comment: I do not disagree, but I will leave this open, as this search term is quite different than the question there.

Comment: I've retitled the original question so that more people can be redirected to it. It's [Embedding C++ Objects into QML with Context Properties](http://askubuntu.com/questions/431368/embedding-c-objects-into-qml-with-context-properties) now.