# How do you use Q_INVOKABLE to access c++ functions in QML?

Tags: application-development, programming, c++, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am looking for the most simple and straightforward example.

For my part;

.h

```
public:
KTerminalDisplay(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
~KTerminalDisplay();
Q_INVOKABLE void setFontStyle(QString & s);
```

.cpp

```
void KTerminalDisplay::setFontStyle(QString & s){
m_fontStyle = QString(s);
}
```

This works fine thus far. No issues. The question is; how do I use this function in a QML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `KTerminalDisplay` instance accessible from QML, you must register it in your `main.cpp`. Since you're expecting parent to be a QQuickItem, your question is not so simple. After looking at the [terminal app](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-terminal-dev/ubuntu-terminal-app/trunk), I can propose the following trick:

```
QQuickItem *item = view.rootObject();
KTerminalDisplay * display = (KTerminalDisplay *) item;
view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("kdisplay", display);
```

Once registered, you can call `setFontStyle` from QML:

```
kdisplay.setFontStyle("foo")
```

**Note**: See [Embedding C++ Objects into QML with Context Properties](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431368/embedding-c-objects-into-qml-with-context-properties) as you can mark your method as a slot.

Source: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Calling_Qt_class_methods_from_QML

Comment: What does '...your view" refer to? I am assuming it is the QQuickView object?

Comment: @Akiva: I've updated my answer with a richer context for the main.cpp

Comment: What is "qtquick2applicationviewer.h" in reference to? The header which contains the kterminaldisplay class?

Comment: @Akiva: Look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/431458/32239), it's a working piece of code that you can reuse. "qtquick2applicationviewer.h" is a Qt header, not your header containing the kterminaldisplay class.

Comment: Yah I just saw that. Unfortunately I do not have a .pro file for this, as this project is using cmakelists. Do you know what to do in that case?

Comment: @Akiva but you have a main.cpp, do you?

Comment: Yes; it looks like this: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8402408/  there is a bit of my code in there while I try to figure this out.

Comment: @Akiva: Well a simple `view.engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("kterminaldisplay", &kTerminalDisplay);` should do it then. Given that you also declared `KTerminalDisplay kTerminalDisplay;` and imported the corresponding header of this class

Comment: unfortunately that is not working. http://i.imgur.com/NHJbfaS.jpg

Comment: @Akiva The errors seem all related to your class actually: try with `QObject *parent` instead of `QQuickItem *parent`

Comment: Unfortunately the terminal app depends on QQuickItem. Changing it mucks up a whole bunch of stuff in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yah from what I can tell; the KTerminal is actually already invokable with a select amount of functions. To everyone else though; this was a application specific issue, and Sylvains solution ordinarily works. Thanks

Comment: @Akiva: After digging in the app code, I've come up with an updated snippet which seems to build (at least) in qt creator. Please tell me if it works for you